# How can we check the content of two different arrays and fetch the corresponding index value from the third array and sum up them?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have 3 arrays:

- `${array1[@]}` - `Application_1 Application_2 Application_3 Application_4 Application_5 Application_6`
- `${array2[@]}` - `60 50 7 9 5 21`
- and `${array3[@]}` - `Application_9 Application_11 Application_2 Application_5 Application_1`

when the contents of `${array3[@]}` compare with `${array1[@]}` and satisfy the equal condition then the corresponding index from `${array2[@]}` should be sum up. For instance,

```
Application_2 
Application_5 
Application_1
```

from `${array3[@]}` satisfy the condition with `${array1[@]}` content with their corresponding index [0, 1 and 4] respectively.

So, now how can we fetch the same index values (60, 50 and 5) from `${array2[@]}`  and sum up them. Point to note is that there will be always the same number of content in `${array1[@]}` and `${array2[@]}`.

How can we go through the loop if we have a really big number of contents in all of the arrays? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, but your array notation is completely not understandable. Could you please edit your question and give a clear example what those array contain?

Comment: You are using the wrong language for this kind of processing.